# Kafka Connect in timestamp mode - how to append to the end of a query?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, db2, apache-kafka-connect

I have a configured source connector, retrieving from DB2 and using timestamp mode. e.g:

```
    "name": "my-jdbc-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:db2://db2server.mycompany.com:4461/myDB",
        "connection.user: "dbUser",
        "connection.password": "dbPass",
        "dialect.name": "Db2DatabaseDialect",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "query": "select fname, lname, custId, custRegion, lastUpdate from CustomerMaster",
        "timestamp.column.name": "lastUpdate",
        "table.types": "TABLE",
        "topic.prefix": "master.customer"
    }
}
```

I need to use "with UR" (with uncommitted read, aka 'dirty read') as part of the select, so as not to lock the table I'm querying from.

But, when using timestamp mode, Kafka Connect appends on to the end of the where clause, as in

```
where lastUpdate between '10/12/2019' and '10/14/2019';
```

DB2 requires that "with UR" be the last thing in the where clause. Does anyone know if manipulating the where clause like this is possible? I don't currently see how timestamp mode and "with UR" can coexist.

Comment: maybe you can use "query.suffix"

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass the dynamic queries on JDBC Kafka Connector. JDBC Connector used to load data incrementally by using a timestamp-based high watermark. This allows bringing data from the Database to the Kafka topic with very minimal configuration code.
So considering this you no need to add an anywhere clause for increment however if you are looking to use where clauses for the static query you can do as mentioned below:

1. Use sub-query as below

> "query": "select * from (select fname, lname, custId, custRegion,
> lastUpdate from CustomerMaster where lastUpdate between '10/12/2019'
> and '10/14/2019' ) o",

2. Create the view on table CustomerMaster and use view on your JDBC connector.

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456759/kafka-connect-possible-to-use-custom-query-with-bulk-mode/58457564?noredirect=1#comment103698846_58457564) for more details

Comment: I don't think the subquery would work, because the dates in the where clause are going to be dynamic, controlled by the timestamp mode. In other words, it can't be specified as part of the query passed to Kafka.

Comment: Oh you not mentioned its dynamic where clause ...JDBC Connector is used for increment increment based on predefined timestamp query you could not pass dynamic where clauses..

Comment: Updated response as well

Comment: What I mean is, when you specify timestamp mode in the source config, Kafka *automatically* creates a dynamic where clause, you can't control it. 
So, my query has no where clause in it (see above), but using 
"mode": "timestamp" and
"timestamp.column.name": "lastUpdate"
Kafka will automatically append "where lastUdate date between... etc."

Comment: Yes u can't control the only way for example u need have last few days that u can embed in where case that means static...not dynamic basically you don't need timestamp in where clause...it already taken care by Connect..

Answer (score 0):

You can trick the Kafka connect timestamp mode appended where clause by wrapping your original query in a `SELECT * FROM ( your query here)` and the Kafka connect where clause will be appended at the end correctly, which allows the query to run and the detection mechanism would work correctly as well so the result is :

```
SELECT * FROM ( your query here) WHERE timestampColumn> ? AND timestampColumn < ?  ORDER BY timestampColumnASC
```